# how to access properties from Laravel collections within foreach

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Laravel collection with relations returned to a view and I need to access it's properties;

**controller**

```
$project = Project::with('pulls.builds')->where('id',$id)->get();
```

**view**

```
@foreach ($project as $project->pulls) 
 {{ $project->pulls }}    
@endforeach
```

**output**

```
{"id":2,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Project Name","pulls":[{"id":2,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"branch":".fixes","project_id":2,"builds":[{"id":3,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"description":"43662-4768-456","pull_id":2}]},{"id":3,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"branch":".test","project_id":2,"builds":[{"id":4,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"description":"build 1","pull_id":3}]}]}
```

I have all the data that I want, now I need to make it look like this when viewed by the user:

```
Project Name

.fixes
43662-4768-456

.test
build 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$projects = Project::with('pulls.builds')->where('id',$id)->get();
```

Given the structure of the json, to echo out every property you'd need to do something like this

```xml
@foreach($projects as $project)
  {{ $project->id }}
  {{ $project->created_at }}
  {{ $project->updated_at }}
  {{ $project->name }}
  @foreach($project->pulls as $pull)
    {{ $pull->id }}
    {{ $pull->created_at }}
    {{ $pull->updated_at }}
    {{ $pull->branch }}
    {{ $pull->project_id }}
    @foreach($pull->builds as $build)
      {{ $build->id }}
      {{ $build->created_at }}
      {{ $build->updated_at }}
      {{ $build->description }}
      {{ $build->pull_id }}
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

So taking only what you need, and adding some html, it could end up looking like this:

```xml
<p>Projects:</p>
@foreach($projects as $project)
  <p>Project Name: <span>{{ $project->name }}</span></p>
  <p>Pulls:</p>
  @foreach($project->pulls as $pull)
    <p>Branch: <span>{{ $pull->branch }}</span></p>
    <p>Builds:</p>
    @foreach($pull->builds as $build)
      <p>Description: <span>{{ $build->description }}</span></p>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you only want a single project, instead of using `->where('id', $id)->get()`, use `->find($id)` and you can remove the first `@foreach`.

Comment: thankyou, I'm fairly new to Laravel and have not yet fuily wrapped my head around when I am returning a Collection or when I am returniing an Object

Comment: Collections are essentially a wrapper for arrays. When you query your models, `->find()` or `->first()` return a single model (Object). `->get()` returns a collection of models for you to iterate over.